# gridview changing position automatically when notifiedDatasetChangedCalled?

Tags: android, gridview

here ia an application where i displaying some text with image background but it got changes position 
automatically when notifieddatasetchanged() is called, please help me how to fixed it constant position ,below is my code. thanks you

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //ImageView imageView;
        View v;
        TextView tv = null;
        if (convertView == null) { 


            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.show_table_gridview, null);
            tv = (TextView)      
                            v.findViewById(R.id.tab_num);
            tv.setText(""+position+1));                 

            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            HashMap<Integer, List<OrderlistData>> orederMap1 = ConText
            .getTotlaMap();
            List<OrderlistData> orderlist1 = new ArrayList<OrderlistData>();
            Set<Integer> keySet1 = orederMap1.keySet();
              if (keySet1.contains(position))
                  orderlist1 = orederMap1.get(position);

              if (orderlist1.isEmpty()){

              }
            else{
              tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
             }
          } 
           else {
            v =  convertView;
        }
        /**
         * Code for changing background if data is content
         */
        return v;
    }
```

here is the code for updating gridview in every 20sec
//=============Refreshing gridview ==============

```
  private class UpdateGridview extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String>
     {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Context... params) {

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
                Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                handler.sendMessage(msg);

                i++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("makemachine", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return "COMPLETE!";
    }

        private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                getCurrent_orderlist_StatusFromServer();
                gridadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                System.out
                        .println("i  called notifyDataSetChanged()=======================");
            }
        };


        // -- gets called just before thread begins
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
                Log.i( "makemachine", "onPreExecute()" );
                super.onPreExecute();

        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) 
        {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        }

        // -- called if the cancel button is pressed
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled()
        {
                super.onCancelled();
               Log.i( "makemachine", "onCancelled()" );

        }

        // -- called as soon as doInBackground method completes
        // -- notice that the third param gets passed to this method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( String result ) 
        {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Log.i( "makemachine", "onPostExecute(): " + result );

        }
```

}

Comment: Can you show the code where you are using notifieddatasetchanged()

Comment: here is the code for updating gridview in every 20sec

Comment: try this adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening like this because you are giving the if condition. It's because at the first time only `convertview` gets assigned. For the second time it's not entering into the if condition. 
And you have to execute the codes within the if. So just remove the if condition, it will work properly.